# How to configure spring boot admin to pass additional headers

Tags: spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-admin

I am using the Spring Boot Admin plugin for my project.
The application that i would like to monitor using my Spring Boot Admin project has been deployed behind a Gateway, and hence to access the Actuator end-points i need to pass certain headers as a part of the request. Is there any way i can configure these additional headers.

Configuring Spring Boot Admin with HTTP Authentication does not suffice.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else searching for an answer for this try referring the [documentation](https://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/2.1.5/#customizing-headers)